# SQLite3 - Library routine called out of sequence

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

When running the following prepare statement for a SQLite3 db-selecct query I get a SQLLite Error 21 "*Library routine called out of sequence*":

```
sqlite3             *lDb;
sqlite3_stmt           *lStmt;
NSNumberFormatter     *lNbrFmt = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

// Define SQL statement 
NSString *lSql = @"SELECT section, language, title, description"
@"                        selector-x-pos, selector-y-pos, gps-x-pos, gps-y-pos"
@"                   FROM sections"
@"               ORDER BY section ASC";

lSqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(lDb, [lSql UTF8String], -1, &lStmt, NULL);
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:sqlite3_errmsg(lDb)]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Congrats on figuring it out! Could you reformat the question and answer for legacy, so that the same error can be resolved easily by future visitors? If not, you should delete the question altogether. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, just edited it ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uopon further investigation I found my mistake. I should have first opened the db before running the prep statement.

The code should look like this:

```
sqlite3             *lDb;
sqlite3_stmt           *lStmt;
NSNumberFormatter     *lNbrFmt = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

// Define SQL statement 
NSString *lSql = @"SELECT section, language, title, description"
@"                        selector-x-pos, selector-y-pos, gps-x-pos, gps-y-pos"
@"                   FROM sections"
@"               ORDER BY section ASC";

if(sqlite3_open([[fileMethods databasePath] UTF8String], &lDb) == SQLITE_OK) {
    lSqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(lDb, [lSql UTF8String], -1, &lStmt, NULL);
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:sqlite3_errmsg(lDb)]);
...
```

Comment: "Library routine called out of sequence" - Or check you don't have the same DB open already elsewhere.. Thanks for the pointer ;)